# SQL documentation wiki

Tags: sql, documentation, wiki

Inspired by how much of an improvement the [MDC Javascript/DOM docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) are over W3Schools, I was looking for a similar wiki comparable to the W3Schools SQL documentation today.  I haven't had much luck.

Is there a wiki documenting all the SQL commands with common-use examples, caveats, and vendor-dependent implementations?

Comment: For SQL Server, MSDN would be the place to check.

Comment: are you looking for just ANSI-SQL, or a vendor-specific site?

Comment: I want a single site which includes ALL vendors.  This format would help make it clear when a query will not perform the same across vendors.

Comment: @entropo Good luck finding it. I don't know that such a site exists. Also, based on comments from high-end professional DB admins, you should pick a RDBMS and then code to its specific strengths and weaknesses (you should not strive for some pure portable SQL).

Comment: @Phrogz: That's unfortunate, something better needs to dethrone W3Schools' [#1 spot on Google for "SQL"](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best documentation usually comes from the source itself. Which documentation you want depends on your RDBMS:

- [**MS SQL Server** Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx) or [Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299742%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [**PostgreSQL** SQL Syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax.html)
- [**SQLite** SQL Syntax](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) *with pretty railroad diagrams*
- [**MySQL** SQL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax.html)
- [**Oracle** SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm)

**Edit**: Based on your updated question, the answer is *"What you want does not exist."*

Comment: I'm familiar with all of these resources.  I want a community-editable source of aggregate info.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your SQL Server tag, you might want to check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299742%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx). Vendors usually maintain decent doc themselves (see [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en) and [Oracle 10g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm))

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in a single vendor.  I want to know when a query will perform differently in e.g. MySQL than Postgre, MS-SQL, SQLite, et al. based on a vendor-agnostic source which is community-editable.

Comment: Oh I see. Then I'm afraid that such a ressource does not exist.